# AVPlayer iphone to play sound even views are changed

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, audio, avplayer

I am developing a music player app where the tracks or sounds are played from the url and I m using AVplayer to play the tracks from the url

Basically i want to keep on playing the tracks even user navigated or goes to new other or the application goes to background !! i really don't have a idea how to achieve the same..

these is the demo code I am using to get the track from the URL

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<#Live stream URL#>];

    // You may find a test stream at <http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8>.

    self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    //(optional) [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&ItemStatusContext];

    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:<#Live stream URL#>];

   //(optional) [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&PlayerStatusContext];
```

i even wanted to play next track if the current played track is over.